# Struts NoSuchMethodError

Tags: struts

I am getting below error while deploying my project in tomcat 7.
I am using struts 1.1 and commons-validator 1.3.1, compiling with jdk 7.

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks.validateRequired(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/apache/commons/validator/ValidatorAction;Lorg/apache/commons/validator/Field;Lorg/apache/struts/action/ActionErrors;Ljavax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest;)Z
    at org.apache.struts.util.StrutsValidator.validateRequired(StrutsValidator.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction.executeValidationMethod(ValidatorAction.java:544)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Field.validateForRule(Field.java:796)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Field.validate(Field.java:876)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Form.validate(Form.java:288)
    at org.apache.commons.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:351)
    at org.apache.struts.validator.ValidatorForm.validate(ValidatorForm.java:116)
    at com.mj.metal.form.administration.SignInForm.validate(SignInForm.java:158)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processValidate(RequestProcessor.java:945)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:198)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    $WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

below is my validator-rules.xml

```
<global>
    <validator name="required" classname="org.apache.struts.util.StrutsValidator" method="validateRequired" methodParams="java.lang.Object,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Field,
                   org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors,
                   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" msg="errors.required">

        <javascript>
            <![CDATA[
        function validateRequired(form) {
            var bValid = true;
            var focusField = null;
            var i = 0;
            var fields = new Array();
            oRequired = new required();
            for (x in oRequired) {
                if ((form[oRequired[x][0]].type == 'text' ||
                     form[oRequired[x][0]].type == 'textarea' ||
                     form[oRequired[x][0]].type == 'select-one' ||
                     form[oRequired[x][0]].type == 'radio' ||
                     form[oRequired[x][0]].type == 'password') &&
                    (form[oRequired[x][0]].value == '')) {
                    if (i == 0) {
                        focusField = form[oRequired[x][0]];
                    }
                    fields[i++] = oRequired[x][1];
                    bValid = false;
                }
            }
            if (fields.length > 0) {
               focusField.focus();
               alert(fields.join('\n'));
            }
            return bValid;
        }]]>
        </javascript>
    </validator>

    <validator name="requiredif" classname="org.apache.struts.validator.FieldChecks" method="validateRequiredIf" methodParams="java.lang.Object,  
                           org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,  
                           org.apache.commons.validator.Field,  
                           org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages,  
                           org.apache.commons.validator.Validator,  
                           javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" msg="errors.required" />

    <validator name="validwhen" msg="errors.required" classname="org.apache.struts.validator.validwhen.ValidWhen" method="validateValidWhen" methodParams="java.lang.Object,  
                   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,  
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Field,  
                   org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessages,  
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Validator,  
                   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" />

    <validator name="minlength" classname="org.apache.struts.util.StrutsValidator" method="validateMinLength" methodParams="java.lang.Object,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.ValidatorAction,
                   org.apache.commons.validator.Field,
                   org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors,
                   javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest" depends="required" msg="errors.minlength">
        <javascript>
            <![CDATA[
        function validateMinLength(form) {
            var bValid = true;
            var focusField = null;
            var i = 0;
            var fields = new Array();
            oMinLength = new minlength();
            for (x in oMinLength) {
                if (form[oMinLength[x][0]].type == 'text' ||
                    form[oMinLength[x][0]].type == 'textarea') {
                    var iMin = parseInt(oMinLength[x][2]("minlength"));
                    if (!(form[oMinLength[x][0]].value.length >= iMin)) {
                        if (i == 0) {
                            focusField = form[oMinLength[x][0]];
                        }
                        fields[i++] = oMinLength[x][1];
                        bValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (fields.length > 0) {
               focusField.focus();
               alert(fields.join('\n'));
            }
            return bValid;
        }]]>
        </javascript>
    </validator>
```

...

Comment: That was deprecated in S1.1 anyway; should be using `FieldChecks`. I mean, you shouldn't be using Struts 1.1 at *all*, for a variety of technical, architectural, and security reasons.

Comment: I cann't change the project to higher version as it is not allowed in my organization. Is there anyway I can solve this issue without changing the version?

Comment: *shrug* Check your lib versions particularly commons-validator, change to the right classname (e.g., `validateRequiredIf` is working), etc. There are *many* reasons to not use this ancient version of an EOLed product.